# How to send an email when order is created in Magento?

Tags: email, magento

Is there any way to send email when an order is initiated? By default there is an option in Magento to get an email upon order completion but not for when the order is initiated/created.

Currently I am getting emails if the order is completed (payment done) by the customer, but I also want to get an email whenever an order is created. In case if the user doesn't go for payment I can get to know that user has currently initiated the order but has not paid yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make your problem more obvious to others coming across it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your email to send you order copy in admin under:

**System / Configuratio / Sales / Sales Email / Order - "Send Order Email Copy To"**

Comment: As it seems in his question he doesn't want the order Email. He wants an Email when the order is not finished yet (cart).